# Postal address auto-complete on profile page

Tags: plugins, php

Is it possible to have an address auto-complete function (Where you enter your house number and post code and it automatically populates the address fields for you) within the Wordpress user profile page?

I'm more than happy to use a plugin if needs be (In fact I'd probably prefer it, this project is already well over budget)

Comment: Plugin requests are off-topic per the [faq], but yes, it is possible though it would require access to a address database to do it. This may not be a small project.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it would be within the budget anyway